# modify color in latex in overleaf

Tags: color

There is [this cv template on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5c6498e358629c78cbe347a2) and I am trying to modify the color of the links that the CV has.

If I change from initial (from namesection)

```
\href{https://www.pgr-me.github.io}{\bf https://www.pgr-me.github.io}
```

to be

```
\href{https://www.pgr-me.github.io}{\color{red}{ https://www.pgr-me.github.io}}
```

the color does change to be red.

But if I change the initial

```
\item Built \href{http://pgr-me.github.io/Microlending/}{\bf explanatory linear regression model} for an
```

to be

```
\item Built \href{http://pgr-me.github.io/Microlending/}{\color{red} explanatory linear regression model} for an
```

it doesn't change the color.

How can I also change the color of the text/links in subsection?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Several users, including me, do not follow external links. So you should post a complete, compilable code here. (And you might try `\item Built \href{http://pgr-me.github.io/Microlending/}{\textcolor{red}{explanatory linear regression model}} for a`.)

Comment: for changing colors of links, url etc, you should change `hyperref` settings.

Comment: Your link above will not work for many users as it enforces a login, however this one should work https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Hyperlinks#Styles_and_colours

Comment: You link doesn't work anymore. Please add a minimal working example here!